# Metrics for performance of Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance

I am trying to measure various metrics for a stored procedure - that we are tinkering with and using under different loading (i.e. size of tables).

So I have drawn up this list of metrics to plot against the other things we are changing.

These are

- disk I/O
- Elapsed time
- CPU time
- Consistent gets
- sort memory/disk used
- Number of rows accessed

Is there any others that might be useful to capture?

Also when capturing this information it will have an impact on the performance. Is there any documentation as to how much this is the case as I was unable to find any

Comment: There are some other metrics that can be useful, such as wait event and time, parsing information, etc.  But why not use Oracle tools designed for profiling . For instance  tkprof, hierarchical profile, dbms_profiler ? They will give you all information about every single line of your code...

Comment: What we are trying to achieve is to work out the scalability of the system in these particular procedures and for the various versions of the software. An ideal graph will be linear and if there is a tipping point it would be nice to know it

Comment: What are you using to capture these metrics? Your last question is not really answerable without knowing that.

Comment: I was going to use autotrace